# Check if site is online with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

Basically i need to check to see if a website on another domain is online.
how would i do this with actionscript 3?

I need to change a piece of text if the app cannot reach a specified server.

any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this other domain one of yours? If so you can simply try to download a page from it and if that fails, display whatever error you need. Note that you will need to put up a crossdomain.xml on the other domain, so flash can connect to it. Now that I think about it you might get a sandbox error if the host is down as well, so it might be worth looking for that as well.

Otherwise you could probably build something using AJAX in javascript, that you communicate to using ExternalInterface.

Comment: thanks, i used your idea of downloading a page. worked fine :)

Comment: Accept the fellow's answer then _Jonatan_, it means a lot.